# Как залить бота на хостинг?

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram, сервер, веб-сервер

Коротко, есть телеграм бот на aiogram (пока работает на long polling е, но перепишу на вебхуки) нужно залить его на хостинг (не впс сервер). Для начала попробовал залить обычный эхо бот из [документации](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/webhook_example.html) согласно ему

```
WEBHOOK_HOST = 'https://your.domain'    # Сюда я ввел домен сайта
WEBHOOK_PATH = ''
WEBHOOK_URL = f"{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}"

# webserver settings
WEBAPP_HOST = ''  # or ip   -> Сюда я попробовал '::' , '0.0.0.0', ip сайта, и попробовал оставить пустым
WEBAPP_PORT = 8350 # -> прост где то увидел что такую поставили
```

Пока не разобрался как полностью залить и решил попробовать запустить через shell через команду python3 echo.py. Не запускается. Ошибка: **Name or service not known**
Решил следовать [этой](https://habr.com/ru/articles/730310/) статье. Следовал до пункта 4, так как «Services» я в ispmanager'е я такого не нашел.

Как правильно задеплоить проект?

Comment: Нельзя его на какой-нибудь pythonanywhere загрузить?

Comment: В том то и дело что нельзя потому, что pythonanywhere там ограничения есть, а бот работает 24/7.

Comment: Это только в бесплатной версии, а за 5 баксов бот работает круглосуточно.

Comment: Есть даже статья на эту тему - https://habr.com/ru/articles/709314/ :)

Comment: Я по ней и сделал себе